# difference between "engage with someone" and "engage someone"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, prepositional-phrases

What is the difference between "engaging with someone" and "engaging someone"? For example, what is the difference between these two expressions:

- How do you engage with your employees?
- How do you engage your employees?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Engage with* somebody means, as others have said, to interact with that person, usually from a position of greater power (managers are frequently exhorted to engage with employees, but rarely the other way round).  *Engage somebody* has many possible meanings, depending on context: the army *engage the enemy*, you may *engage somebody in conversation* by simply going up and speaking to him, a pretty girl may *engage* (or *behave engagingly to*) the man she is interested in.  The basic meaning  is 'get involved with', which is similar to but not the same as the buzzword *engage with*.

And, as Barrie says, the usual meaning without explanation of *engage a man* is to hire him (at least in Britain).

Comment: "...engage a man or woman" is to "hire them" :) (although a suggested edit was rejected in the review queue, and in the end only a typo was fixed, I do think the anonymous editor had a point)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: you are entitled to your own views on style, but not to impose them on me.

Comment: I wouldn't dream of doing so, I thought you might have been interested, that's all. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

The expressions mean the same thing, so I'd pick the shorter one.

However, "engage" is a bit of a buzzword. I'd phrase this differently, depending on what's really meant. For example:

- How do you *motivate* your employees?
- How do you *challenge* your employees?
- How do you *encourage open communication with* your employees?
- How do you *propose marriage to* your employees? (Just kidding.)

Answer (score 0):

*Engage employees* means recruit employees. *Engage with employees* means interact with them in a postive and mutually beneficial way.

Comment: I would never have taken "engage" to mean "recruit". I'm an American; perhaps that has some relevance?

Comment: @Nathan Long: Toggling [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=engage+staff&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for *"engage staff"* between British and American gives no indication that the usage is specifically British.

Comment: @Barrie England: Whilst it's true *"engage **with** employees"* can only have the meaning you give (i.e. - it never means *hire, recruit* with *"with"*), you can validly speak of art which *"engages its audience"*, for example. It's just that given *"employees"* in the context, we're drawn to one particular interpretation unless there are other reasons to reject it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: True, but the OP asks about the verb as it applies to people, and specifically employees.

Comment: Yes, but Nathan obviously sees *both* forms as having the *proactively interact* sense anyway. And I must just say that even in *"engage [with] the audience"*, I see the preposition as shifting the meaning. Without it, you can be talking about the art *"reaching out"* to a still  potentially somewhat "passive" audience. If you *do* use the preposition, it more strongly implies forcing a two-way interaction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: May be, but if you use 'engage' transitively in the same sentence as 'employees' you risk ambiguity.

Comment: is using "engage" as described by @Barrie England making it a false friend of the French "engager" (to employ)?