# Does the phrase "engage with" imply anything about power differences?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I was under the impression that there was no implied power difference in the usage of the phrase. But I came across an answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/60853) that mentioned that *engaging with* someone is taken to mean interacting with them "usually from a position of greater power".

I've often seen the phrase used in contexts like, "The government refused to engage with the anarchists." But now that I think of it, I can't recall seeing it used for someone with less power.

Would it be ok to say something like, "The priest was advised to spend more time *engaging with* the bishop."? Would it offend your business client if you told them that you hope to *engage with* them frequently in the first stage of the project?

Comment: *The anarchists refused to engage with the government* is also fine - what the word implies is just that the other side was prepared to talk. If you say *we will engage with you frequently in the first stage of the project*, you are (therefore) assuming that they are going to be happy to speak to you - but a) that sounds like a reasonable assumption and b) it is neutralised by *hope* anyway. I wouldn't worry about offending the client.

Comment: Thanks @Minty. Just to be clear, are you saying that the phrase "engage with" doesn't inherently imply anything about power differences - any such implication comes from the context?

Comment: I agree with @Minty, and with your assessment of the opinion

Answer (score 1):

Engage in modern times no longer holds any real idea surrounding power difference - you can see from the [basic definition on google](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=ohEjXdihL8PerQHajZfQAg&q=engage&oq=engage&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39l2j0i20i263j0i67l2j0i131i67j0l3j0i67.196.598..653...0.0..0.293.758.2-3......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..0i131..11%3A1j12%3A2j13%3A0.-2bZhsARqBc):

> 1. Occupy, attract, or involve (someone's interest or attention).
> 2. Participate or become involved in.

But it is definitely rooted in the idea.  You start to see this in the 2nd and 3rd definition from Merriam Webster:

> 2 a obsolete : to entangle or entrap in or as if in a snare or bog b :
>   **to attract and hold by influence or power** c : to interlock with : MESH
>   also : to cause (mechanical parts) to mesh engage the clutch
>
> 3: to bind (someone, such as oneself) to do something especially : to
>   bind by a pledge to marry

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/engage

The word originates from Old French *Engagier*, which means 'to pledge', which further brings power into the picture.

Further breaking up the word, the idea of a power difference becomes even more relevant.

The prefix 'En' starts innocently enough:

> ..general sense “to cause (a person or thing) to be in” the place,
>   condition, or state named by the stem;

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/en-

But then when you consider the word 'gage', the idea of a challenge or power difference becomes even more clear.

> **Gage**
>
> 1. something, as a glove, thrown down by a medieval knight in token
>      of challenge to combat.
> 2. Archaic. a challenge.
> 3. Archaic. a pledge or
>      pawn; security.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/gage

So you could say while the word no longer carries these meanings - it certainly seems to have strong roots surrounding power differences.